# CDK Virtual Scrolling wrong values seen when scrolling due to components having injected properties

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I have an Angular16 Application that is using Angular's CDK virtual scrolling module - https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview.

The components being scrolled (lets say ProductComponent) have child components that use Angular token injection to access a property from its parent, one particular instance (lets say ProductNameComponent) is showing the wrong product name after scrolling.

So, I have displayed the name within the ProductComponent (on the right side) and displayed the name as a button within the ProductNameComponent (on the left side), having scrolled up and down a few times you start to notice the names start to differ.

Having dug around for a while I have verified the name displayed by the ProductComponent is correct, its just the ProductNameComponent that is wrong.

I have reproduced my issue in Stackblitz as cant share the real code, and I found it works when using Input bindings to pass the object down to the ProductNameComponent but not when using the injection approach as per the current implementation.

I was hoping I could get this working as is with the injection approach, but I've not been able to resolve this issue... so it is reproduced in Stackblitz here, if anyone can direct me that would be great.

https://angular-cdk-demo-virtual-scroll-nrnsxq.stackblitz.io

[image]

I initially tried triggering change detection after scrolling, but now it seems as it caches components the injection is somehow impacting what is being displayed

Comment: Suspect its similar issue to this one raised here except the solution does not apply as I am not using @Input https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16330#issuecomment-514591282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` set on `PersonNameComponent`, here change detection runs only when the `@Input` changes or events are fired, since you are using a dependency injection of parent logic, change detection never runs! You can fix it by removing `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

demo with no change detection on `PersonNameComponent`

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-demo-virtual-scroll-m8dmrz?file=app%2Fvirtual-scroll%2Fvirtual-scroll.component.ts,app%2Fvirtual-scroll%2Fvirtual-scroll.component.html,app%2Fperson-name%2Fperson-name.component.ts)

---

Why not use the standard method of sending props `@Input` why are we going for component injection, since that works great and is the easiest solution to your question!

person component html

```
<app-person-name [person]="person"></app-person-name>
<div>{{ person.name }}</div>
```

person-name component ts

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-person-name',
  templateUrl: './person-name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./person-name.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class PersonNameComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() person!: { name: string };

  constructor() {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {}

  public logPerson(): void {
    console.log(this.person);
  }
}
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-demo-virtual-scroll-ujigpa?file=app%2Fvirtual-scroll%2Fvirtual-scroll.component.ts,app%2Fvirtual-scroll%2Fvirtual-scroll.component.html,app%2Fperson-name%2Fperson-name.component.ts,app%2Fperson%2Fperson.component.html,app%2Fperson-name%2Fperson-name.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this has worked in the demo, unfortunately has not solved the issue in my source code though. I don't know the original reason injection was used, am looking to see if I can change implementation but I think I've seen the problem and its that we have a lot being processed during OnInit which doesn't get run again so as the virtual scrolling reuses the components any OnInit processing is lost when a new object is passed in

Comment: @sfaulkner When scroll happens an event will be fired, during this event, you need to take a view child of all the scroll elements and call `detectionChanges()` of `ComponentDetectorRef` this will show the latest value, but `@Input` is the simplest fix, followed by removing `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Comment: I tried Input and removing `OnPush` from the stackblitz demo and then added an additional property in the PersonNameComponent that is populated when ngOnInit is executed and I still have the same problem for this new property so the issue of code in the constructor / ngOnInit is our problem it seems. Unfortunately we have a bunch of logic in either constructor or ngOnInit, our example is more complicated in that we have multiple and complex child components that are impacted by this so would require a sizeable refactor to resolve. Thanks for your direction appreciate it

Comment: @sfaulkner Keep change detection as onpush but use `@Input` but move the `ngOnInit` code to ngOnChanges it might help resolve the issue!

Comment: I did try that but in some of the components there is a lot of processing which will occur every time there is scrolling. have used `templateCacheSize: 0` for now as loading only a subset into the DOM has had a large improvement and this way its not re-using components so OnInit is triggered when scrolling components back into view. Not ideal but see enough improvement at the minute, the refactor needed for the ideal outcome is not something I can fit in at present. Thanks again, very helpful